# Error in creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I got the following exception in my first spring transaction exercise :

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) at
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) at
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) at 
com.Main.main(Main.java:15) 
Caused by:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory  at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:51) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 12 more 
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.entity.Document.person, referenced property unknown: com.entity.Person.x  at
org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:158) at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1586) at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1359) at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724) at
org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
... 18 more
```

This is my Spring configuration file called spring.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!--SpringMVC-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <!--<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class='true'/>-->
    <!-- SpringTransaction-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop><!--for product update-->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="username" value="saba"/>
        <property name="password" value="myjava123"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this my service that I used `@Transactional` annotation

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService<T> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void register(T entity)
    {
         entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Why did this exception happen??

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the stacktrace?

Comment: @Patrick I edit the question.

Comment: Looks like your problem has nothing to do with Spring, actually your Hibernate mapping is wrong.
See these lines `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.entity.Document.person, referenced property unknown: com.entity.Person.x`

Comment: @Patrick Oh thank you I have a problem in OneToOne annotation in one of my entity in defining mappedBy value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your problem has nothing to do with Spring or Transactions.
As your stacktrace shows, you have a problem somewhere with your Hibernate mapping:

```
...
caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Unknown mappedBy in: com.entity.Document.person, referenced property unknown: com.entity.Person.x
...
```